# Run a command from a script directly to another process

Tags: linux, bash, sh, simscript

I'm currently working on a script which interact with another process. 
If it is relevant, the said process is a simdebug console. What I want is exiting it properly because when I kill the process itself, it creates a lock file .lck.
The Simdebug console is waiting for inputs and closes on receiving quit, then q and n, both sperated by an enter keypress to validate the command.

I managed to send some commands to the Simdebug using

```
echo quit > /proc/< PID >/fd/1
```

But it only print the results of the echo and I can't find how to send a enter keypress, only new lines '\n' .

I can't aswell manage to send a quit command which would execute directly in the Simdebug and not the terminal where it is sent from.

My question would be resolved if one of those two points is answered:

- Is it possible to simulate a validate keypress as in :
  Term 1 : echo ifconfig ; echo < enter keypress> 
  Which would then execute what's in the read buffer of the Term 2
- Is there a way to already execute a commande in another process as in

Term 1 : < unknown syntax > pwd

Term 2 < shows pwd of term2 not term1>

Which would not be working only from terminal to terminal but with an already opened process in read mode.

Comment: Hummm... you are sending the `echo` to `stdout` (1), but you should send it to `stdin` (0), right? You want the process to receive that input, no to write on its output.

Comment: Yes this is what I would like to do. I'll see if I find something related to what you said.

Comment: EDIT: I tried to send to fd/0 as you pointed out but I end up with the same results: echo quit > (...) Just prompt quit without validating it. And quit > (...) isn't recognized by the terminal as it is a built-in fonction of the process I'm trying to close.

Comment: You say "a script which interact with another process". Why can't the script send the quit command?

Comment: Well that's actually my question. I'm looking for a way to do it. To answer your question, from what I've gathered, I can't "send" a command easily. I can send the output or results of a command ran into a terminal to a process but so far I haven't found a way to transmit an entire command to the proc, below are some hints on how to do it. I'm open to your suggestions if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a *hard* thing to do. If you send characters to the /proc/self/fd/0 device or similar stdin device link from a different master terminal then it will just output the characters to the output side of the master terminal of the other process.

With tools like `expect` or `pdip` or `screen` you can send anything you want to a process encapsulated in their pseudoterminals as if it comes from their master terminal. But if a process is running then it will already have it's own terminal.

You can be in luck if your console can be persuaded for a controlling terminal transfer with `reptyr`.

For example if your console has process id 999999 (and you have `screen` and `reptyr` installed and maybe did something to appease selinux or apparmor/yama protections):

```
screen -dmS automateconsole
screen -S automateconsole -p 0 -X stuff 'reptyr 999999^M'
screen -S automateconsole -p 0 -X stuff 'quit^M'
sleep 1s
screen -S automateconsole -p 0 -X stuff 'q^M'
sleep 1s
screen -S automateconsole -p 0 -X stuff 'n^M'
sleep 1s
screen -S automateconsole -p 0 -X stuff 'exit^M'
```

But note:

- You probably should cleanup the program that init'ed the console.
- On Ubuntu at least I could not `reptyr` processes from other SSH sessions.

https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr

http://theterminallife.com/sending-commands-into-a-screen-session/

Comment: Well thanks a lot for your answer and your time. I'll have some things to dig into and research about that reptyr and screen. Glad to have something to look into. Will comment with results/ follow up questions during next week

Comment: After a few time of trying, i can't manage to validate / emulate enter keypress so that the stuff function would be executed by the process. Is it why you wrote those ^M ? Anyway I tried with these, and \n, \012, \015 aswell, can't manage to send the command through though.

Comment: Yes, the Control-M is just the normal <enter>. You could try `tmux` instead of screen, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13954